# Props mix when using the same component multiple times on a page in React

Tags: reactjs

I have created the following component in React

```
<CatFood
  name="Cat Food 1"
  onFoodUploaded={foods=> this.setState({catFood1: this.state.catFood1.concat(foods)})}
/>
```

This component has a button to upload foods (this is an example :)).

When I use this component twice, one after the other on the same page

```
    <CatFood
      name="Cat Food 1"
      onFoodUploaded={foods=> this.setState({catFood1: this.state.catFood1.concat(foods)})}
    />
.....
Some Code
.....
    <CatFood
      name="Cat Food 2"
      onFoodUploaded={foods=> this.setState({catFood2: this.state.catFood2.concat(foods)})}
    />
```

For some reason when I upload food on the second component ("Cat Food 2"), it sets the state for "Cat Food 1" and `catFood1` is being updated...

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

The issue for me was that I included an input element to upload the file. I have also attached to it a label with a `htmlFor` attribute which points to its id.

The input id was the same for both of the components so once I clicked on the label of the second component, it found the input label of the first component and uploaded the file through there.

Comment: where does the `foods` parameter coming from when you pass it to the arrow function?

Comment: You should write your update as an answer, that was the problem for me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing things like that in the render() may have some side effects. It is considered bad practice.

I just wrote a little code, very close to what you are trying to achieve. I hope this helps you.

```jsx
import React from 'react'


class FoodUploader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleUpload = (e) => {

    const key = e.target.id

    // Here is a good place to define your value variable
    const value = "foods"

    // Keeps the existing state and adds the new one
    // Not very useful in this case, but may be for your case
    let stateObj = {};

    // Create our stateObj with a dynamic key
    stateObj[key] = value

    // Pass our stateObj to the state
    this.setState(stateObj)
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Food Upload</h1>
      <p>{this.state && this.state.catFood1}</p>
      <p>{this.state && this.state.catFood2}</p>
      <br/>
        {/* Replace onClick with onFoodUploaded */}
        {/* Replace div with CatFood */}
        <div
          name="Cat Food 1"
          id="catFood1"
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
        >Cat Food 1</div>

        <div
          name="Cat Food 2"
          id="catFood2"
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
        >Cat Food 2</div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FoodUploader
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code sample, you use `onFileUploaded` as your event handler. In your second code sample, you use `onFoodUploaded`. This may not be your main problem, but it will certainly cause some problems!

Comment: My mistake, I have fixed that

Comment: Can you add the code for your onFoodUploaded function and also share all of your code for your CatFood component?